# How to make a Python script restart itself if it gets an error and stops if it doesn't?

Tags: python

I have a script that gets errors and I want to make it restart when it gets an error and stop restarting when it doesn't.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! this question could use some clarity and should probably show some effort of research. Here's a vague comment to match: it might help if you had another layer of scripting to control your python script execution. Or, use try except blocks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put the script contents inside a `while True` loop, and only break out of the loop when you get no errors.

```
while True:
    try:
        # do stuff
        # do more stuff
        # yet more stuff

        # if we made it to this line, no exceptions were raised, so break the outer loop
        break
    except Exception as ex:
        print(f"Oops got an error: {ex}")
        # the loop will keep going
```